# How to get first and last value on one row in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, window-functions

Input:

```
postgres=> select player_1, row_number() over (order by id) as r1, row_number() over (order by id desc) as r2 from (select id, player_1 from matches order by id limit 5) as foo;

      player_1      | r1 | r2 
--------------------+----+----
 Kafelnikov Yevgeny |  1 |  5
 Dreekmann Hendrik  |  2 |  4
 Courier Jim        |  3 |  3
 Krajicek Richard   |  4 |  2
 Rafter Patrick     |  5 |  1

(5 rows)
```

Expected:

```
      first      | last
--------------------+----+----
 Kafelnikov Yevgeny |  Rafter Patrick
```

I tried the following, but it has 5 rows, I need them both on a single row, like above.

```
postgres=> select case when r1 = 1 then player_1 end, case when r2 = 1 then player_1 end from (select player_1, row_number() over (order by id) as r1, row_number() over (order by id desc) as r2 from (select id, player_1 from matches order by id limit 5) as foo) as too;
        case        |      case      
--------------------+----------------
 Kafelnikov Yevgeny | 
                    | 
                    | 
                    | 
                    | Rafter Patrick
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can use these row numbers to do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    max(player_1) filter(where r1 = 1) first_player,
    max(player_1) filter(where r2 = 1) last_player
from (
    select player_1, 
        row_number() over (order by id) as r1, 
        row_number() over (order by id desc) as r2 
    from (select * from matches order by id limit 5) t
    order by id limit 5
) t;
```

Note that you  can also do this with `first_value()` and `distinct`:

```
select distinct
    first_value(player_1) over(order by id) first_player,
    first_value(player_1) over(order by id desc) last_player
from (select * from matches order by id limit 5) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=26943c700efa5640e178b9a1a07590f1)**

Answer (score 1):

One other way to do it would be as below -

```
select 
    max(case when r1 = 1 then player_1 end) as first_player,
    max(case when r2 = 1 then player_1 end) as last_player
from (
      select player_1, 
             row_number() over (order by id) as r1, 
             row_number() over (order by id desc) as r2 
        from (select * from mytable order by id limit 3) t
       order by id limit 5
     ) t;
```